# How can i check if the Look Up Field User is the Same user in the Specific Queue using Formula Field

Tags: queue, salesforce, lookup, processbuilder

Thanx for helping,
I have a specific scenario which is used in the Approval Process
I have a LookUp to the user called Project Manager
I wan to check if the Project Manager is the same as the User Reside in Queue I have only one user in the Queue

Is there any way I can check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in pure process builder. You could query this data. Queues are a type of Group object in Salesforce and they have a related list of Group Members. So something like that:

```
SELECT Group.Name, UserOrGroupId
FROM GroupMember
WHERE Group.Type = 'Queue' AND Group.DeveloperName= 'X'
```

Or

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM User
WHERE Id IN (SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE Group.DeveloperName = 'X')
```

Should give you some ideas.

If you have a simple process maybe you're willing to rewrite it into Flow? Should support queries nicely. (personally I'm not a fan of flows but hey, it's a valid option)

Or if you want to keep it in Process you can have some success with writing small piece of apex and calling [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm).

Or make a checkbox or (multi)picklist with Queue names? Or something like that on the User if it has to be a simple formula...

Comment: How can I use the formula field, to check it's only available to get the owner of the Queue not the Queue memeber that reside in it

Comment: You can't. Formulas can go only "up", like Opportunity -> Account -> Owner -> Profile -> Name. (not sure why you'd need a formula like that but you can make one). What you're asking for is to go "up" (via lookup to Queue definition), then "down" to rel. list of queue members. Not doable.

Comment: can we talk a little over skype ifrahimafzal.awan_1

Comment: I have also asked the question over salesforce community can you please describle the flow option to this solution   
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000a4HtQAI

Comment: Sorry mate, still lots of work stuff to complete today and it's already 9 PM. There are lots of tutorials about Flows, "fast lookup" actions... Try reading https://automationchampion.com/tag/assignment-in-flow/ and training modules at https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/trails/build-flows-with-flow-builder. To be fair you're asking about config solution (formula, flow) not coding so you might have more luck at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have taken the path of the flow it's quite completed

Comment: by the way, I have gone with the process builder but your answer help me a lot @eyescream